# Installing CouchDB 2.1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb-2.x

Does anyone know how to install CouchDB on Ubuntu Server 16.04?

The manual in the [CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/install/unix.html) seems to be broken and a simple `apt-get install couchdb`results in Version 1.6.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the snap for CouchDB, there isn't an apt package for CouchDB 2.1 yet.  http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/snap.html.  (If this is what you already tried from the manual and it didn't work, share any error messages you received)

Comment: It can be install by apt, just needs to be added to the sources.list

Comment: sudo snap install couchdb
`error: snap "couchdb" not found` I get this message on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18. 2 weeks ago same server, fresh install, worked. Now I get this error

Comment: I get the same:  `error: snap "couchdb" not found' on ubuntu 18

Comment: Try searching; there may be more than one couchdb package available.
`snap find couchdb`

Answer (score 9):

This will install CouchDB 2.1:

1. Add "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main" to /etc/apt/sources.list using your favorite editor
2. Add the public key to apt:

   curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -
3. Depending on your setup you may need to install https for apt

   sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
4. Update apt and install!

   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install couchdb

Comment: This is really works on Ubunut 16.04 I have a lot of issues with current version from official website - try to use old version of erlang, but install couchdb 2.1 is resolve all issues.

Answer (score 1):

I setup CouchDB 2.1.1 on a Digital Ocean droplet, running on Ubuntu 16 (xenial), with HTTPS (using a Let's encrypt free certificate).

Rough steps where as follows,

- Initial server set-up, followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04
- Configured a domain using the Digital Ocean WebUI

  - Added an A Name record via my DNS registers site to point to my droplet's public IP
- Configured a firewall using the Digital Ocean WebUI and associated it with my droplet

  - Enabled the following inbound ports,

    - 80 for certbot
    - 5984 CouchDB HTTP - enabled until HTTPS configured and then disabled
    - 6984 CouchDB HTTPS
- Installed CouchDB by following the oficial docs (worked for me), http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/install/unix.html
- Generated SSL Certificate using the Let's encrypt certbot application, https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-other

  - sudo certbot certonly (option 1 standalone)
- Setup a crontab to run certbot renew every week

  - Modified CouchDB local.ini to use the newly generated certificate (PEM files), see https://serverfault.com/questions/743452/configure-couchdb-with-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate

I later saw the following which was close to what I did and one of the better guides available, 
https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-couchdb-database-on-an-ubuntu-server-digital-ocean/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to install coushDB **2.x** on Ubuntu 16.04 : https://github.com/afiskon/install-couchdb :

```
 mkdir temp
 cd temp
 wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/afiskon/install-couchdb/master/install-couchdb.sh
sh install-couchdb.sh
# then see http://localhost:5984/_utils/
```