# is it possible to install couchdb 2.x via apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, ubuntu-16.04

This might be a noob question but is it possible to install couchdb 2.x via apt-get?
When I `apt-get install couchdb -y` I always get version 1.6.x

`apt-cache policy couchdb` gives me:

```
couchdb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6.0-0ubuntu7
  Version table:
     1.6.0-0ubuntu7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing CouchDB 2.1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004317/installing-couchdb-2-1-on-ubuntu-server-16-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. This was basically answered before:

[Installing CouchDB 2.1 on Ubuntu Server 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004317/installing-couchdb-2-1-on-ubuntu-server-16-04)

there are multiple ways.
The one that worked for me was the one from MadPink:

- Add "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main" to `/etc/apt/sources.list` using your favourite editor
- `curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
- `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install couchdb`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you'll need to use the project's own package repository (the version of CouchDB isn't going to be updated in the main repo as far as I know).  You can find instructions here http://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/install/unix.html on how to add the repo and install the package (warning, remove your existing couchdb installation first.  The data should come across OK without needing any migration steps but make sure you have a backup anyway)

Comment: that is what I basically tried to do but `apt-get install` installs the wrong version. Or are you saying to install it manually?

Comment: Ah I see you found your own answer :)  On the installation instructions that I linked to, it shows how to add that extra repo to apt as you put in your own answer.